# Mapping between Sovrin Nets and genesys files

Tags: hyperledger-indy, indy-node

[Here](https://sovrin.org/overview/) is is mentioned that there are three Sovrin Networks:

- MainNet (prod)
- StageNet (pre-prod)
- BuilderNet (test)

But I can not find genesis files for those networks.

In sovrin github https://github.com/sovrin-foundation/sovrin/tree/master/sovrin

There are some genesis files but their names do not match with the nets above.

Where can I find the proper genesis files or mapping between the names?